# Rails 3.1.1 Guard-rspec cannot run due to Growl errors: OSERROR: -10000 MESSAGE: Apple event handler failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, guard, growl

I have been running Guard for RSPEC and using the growl_notify gem for a while now (2-3 months), but now I cannot get `guard` to run in any of my Rails 3.1.1 projects. I've done some research on the error itself, but couldn't come up with anything conclusive (except [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632785/unable-to-run-growl-notifications-and-gem-growl-notify-throws-errors) has the same issue).

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'spreadsheet' # Allows for reading/writing Excel files. We also need a CSV importer, but that can come later
gem 'gmaps4rails' # Allows for Google Maps Pushpins/Markers/Places
gem 'scoped_search' # For Searching
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git" # For File Uploads

group :test, :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'turn', '<0.8.3'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'growl_notify'
    gem 'launchy'
    gem 'capistrano' #You don't want Capistrano on the production side (I think)
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg' #use postgres for database installation as the database
end
```

Error:

```
Thomas@Thomas-Cannons-MacBook-Pro:~/development/rails/tasks$ guard
/Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib/appscript.rb:542:in `_send_command': CommandError (Appscript::CommandError)
        OSERROR: -10000
        MESSAGE: Apple event handler failed.
        COMMAND: app("/Library/PreferencePanes/Growl.prefPane/Contents/Resources/GrowlHelperApp.app").register({:all_notifications=>["success", "pending", "failed", "notify"], :as_application=>"Guard", :default_notifications=>"notify"})
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib/appscript.rb:642:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/growl_notify-0.0.3/lib/growl_notify.rb:29:in `register'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/growl_notify-0.0.3/lib/growl_notify.rb:19:in `config'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/lib/guard/notifiers/growl_notify.rb:42:in `available?'
from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-    0.9.4/lib/guard/notifier.rb:117:in `add_notification'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/lib/guard/notifier.rb:154:in `block in auto_detect_notification'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/lib/guard/notifier.rb:154:in `each'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/lib/guard/notifier.rb:154:in `any?'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/lib/guard/notifier.rb:154:in `auto_detect_notification'
from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-    0.9.4/lib/guard/notifier.rb:80:in `turn_on'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/lib/guard.rb:184:in `start'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/lib/guard/cli.rb:74:in `start'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-    0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-    0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-0.9.4/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/guard:19:in `load'
    from /Users/Thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/guard:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: i just ran into the same issue

Answer (score 7):

Here's what worked for me. Two things:

First, Guard 0.10.x. requires Growl >= 1.3. Install Growl 1.3 from the App Store (thew reviews are really bad, but I had no trouble).

Second, the new Guard versions recommend `ruby_gntp`. Simply replace `gem 'growl_notify'` with `gem 'ruby_gntp'`.

Comment: Go the gem 'ruby_gntp' if youre on snow leopard

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a version mismatch between Growl and growl_notify.  growl_notify 0.0.3 changed the Growl application name, which near as I can tell changed with Growl 1.3 (Lion only)

I believe it works out to:

- use growl_notify 0.0.2 for Growl < 1.3
- use growl_notify 0.0.3 for Growl >= 1.3
- use growl gem (what I did)

Comment: Don't forget to uninstall other gems (e.g. remove growl_notify if you're using growl gem).